# Jquery Ui Sortable showing broken image in IE8

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui, internet-explorer-8

I have a query sortable collection of images, ie. the items is set to img (due to the fact it is in a tab control and is a horizontal list,  cannot be sorted on the list items, I just can't get it to work), which works perfectly everywhere except for IE8 (even in standards compliance mode), where the placeholder shows a broken image.  Is there any kind of CSS setting I can use to make the placeholder invisible in IE8.  I have tried

```
visibility : hidden;
```

I have tried setting the

```
content : url(transparent.gif);
```

neither seeming to have any effect.  What can I do to fix this?  Any suggestions on how I can even examine what CSS is being shown, as in Dom Explorer (or whatever its called in the IE8 developer tools) I can't see the img because as soon as I let go of the mouse it disappears and Dom Explorer doesn't seem to do real time updating the way Firebug does.

Edit:  Here is the probelm duplicated http://jsbin.com/irozu

I over simplified my example, the other problem is that the whole tab is scrollable, controlled by slider.  Changing

```
display : inline;
```

to

```
float : left;
```

doesn't work as we no longer have a scrollable list of items.  Also for some strange reason, when there is a scrollbar and you use "li" instead of "img" as the target, the sortable stops working.

The updated example is at: http://jsbin.com/ahawi.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **where the placeholder shows a broken image**. Is there any kind of CSS setting I can use to make the placeholder invisible in IE8. I have tried

the broken image appears because jQuery UI creates (in your case) an IMG element without src attribute set for a placeholder. To solve this problem:

1. don't set the placeholder option
   or
2. change your .showPlace class to something like

   ```
   .showPlace {
      margin: 20px;
      overflow: hidden;
      width: 0; height: 0;
   }
   ```

the code above will hide the (non-existing) image content, but will leave the element visible.

BTW. in my test-case, setting `visibility: hidden` to `.showPlace` also worked well

Answer (score 1):

If you do not want to show a placeholder, make sure that you *do not* set the sortable's `placeholder` option.

I see no problem with the default sortable behaviour in IE8. I've tried to recreate what you described in this hosted example: http://jsbin.com/osobu (The sortable images are in the third tab.)

It would be helpful if you provided more code or just edit the sample I provided (via http://jsbin.com/osobu/edit) in order to duplicate the problem.

**Edit**

In response to your comment, you can just set the `items` option to `"li"` and the problem is fixed. Also, I have to you use

```
#images li { float: left; }
```

instead of

```
#images li { display: inline: }
```

or else the image will be offset while you are dragging it.

Here is the fixed demo: http://jsbin.com/osezu

Comment: That's an awesome tool (jsbin.com), here is the problem duplicated:

http://jsbin.com/irozu

Comment: Yup, jsbin.com is an excellent tool, especially for StackOverflow. The only problem is that it will delete code that has not been visited in 30 days, so it's usually a good idea to include the code and/or a description of the demo in your comments for future use.

Comment: Once I get this sorted out, I'll include the code in the question for posterity.  BTW I have moved all the javascript in the sample to the HTML portion just for clarity for when I add it to the question.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it up and reduced the code quite a bit.

Main problem was you were setting the DIV sortable rather than the UL

Seems to work just the way you want it : http://jsbin.com/egiwu

Comment: This works because you removed the placeholder option in sortable, not because of changing from DIV to UL.  See http://jsbin.com/uxufe .

Answer (score 0):

You could try: `display: none;`.

Comment: I want the space to display, just not the borken img container.  display: none will get rid of the space.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another workaround:

```
$('.mysortthings').sortable({
  start: function(event,ui) {
        $('.ui-sortable-placeholder').each( function() {
           this.setAttribute('src','/ico/unipixel.gif'); } );
       }
});
```

In other words, set a start event handler, which sets the 'src' attribute of the placeholder img, as soon as things get going.